# Experiment to determine the relation between applied voltage and angle of output shaft of a DC Servo motor?

Tags: motor, dc, pid-controller

My project need to control the position of a DC Servo motor, but I don't know the plant model of my motor. So, I want to make an experiment to acquire the data between the applied voltage and angle of rotate shaft, after that I can use "System Identification Toolbox",in Matlab, to model my motor. There for I can choose PID parameters to control my motor position.
I work on an Arduino Uno board and a L298 driver. Please tell me how to do the experiment to acquire date for "System Identification Toolbox". Thank you !

Comment: While there are many types of systems in existence, a servo drive with a voltage input usually interprets it as a velocity command, not a position one.

Answer (score 1):

There's not necessarily any correlation between the applied voltage and the shaft angle.  (Suppose the rotor is locked for example, no matter what voltage you apply the angle is the same.)  Servo motors use some sort of sensor/encoder for position and/or velocity feedback.

Your particular servo motor might have a position sensor like Hall effect devices, or an optical encoder or a resolver, but without any data on your motor we don't know.

There are techniques for brushless motors (especially in salient pole motors) to do sensorless measurement of the approximate shaft angle, but they are relatively complex, you can't just use the applied motor voltage.

Comment: [Here ](http://uk.mathworks.com/videos/data-driven-control-how-to-design-a-controller-when-plant-model-is-not-available-81897.html)
is the article that I have seen. But I don't know the coonection between Arduino and the Motor to acquire the data.

Comment: This really depends on what you are talking about when you say "applied voltage".  If your motor includes drivers and some sort of feedback, and the "applied voltage" you are talking about is a control input, then it's possible to do some experiments to find the relation between the control input and the mechanical output of the motor.  As Chris stated that relationship could well be angular velocity per volt, not position.  You could estimate relative position by integrating the velocity, but it wouldn't be very accurate over time.